# Graphical issues Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I am running Ubuntu 18.10, on the dell xps 13. I have this issue with the graphics where the bottom part of the screen is preserving the last pixels it had and is flickering.

I have googled some things but it seems like no one knows what the problem is. I have tried resetting "tweaks" back to default with no affect. I have updated the PC and still nothing.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Any ideas?

11am Edit: I re-installed the OS and formatted the disk and the same issue persists.

Edit: This happened when it was connected to my TV using a usb-c -> hdmi adapter. The TV went to sleep and the PC opened up like this.

Edit 2:

```
    WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gir1.2-freedesktop/cosmic,now 1.58.0-1 amd64 [installed]
hwdata/cosmic-updates,cosmic-updates,now 0.290-1ubuntu0.18.10.1 all [installed]
libfontenc1/cosmic,now 1:1.1.3-1 amd64 [installed]
libice6/cosmic,now 2:1.0.9-2 amd64 [installed]
libsm6/cosmic,now 2:1.2.2-1 amd64 [installed]
libx11-6/cosmic,now 2:1.6.7-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libx11-data/cosmic,cosmic,now 2:1.6.7-1 all [installed]
libx11-xcb1/cosmic,now 2:1.6.7-1 amd64 [installed]
libxau6/cosmic,now 1:1.0.8-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxaw7/cosmic,now 2:1.0.13-1 amd64 [installed]
libxcomposite1/cosmic,now 1:0.4.4-2 amd64 [installed]
libxdamage1/cosmic,now 1:1.1.4-3 amd64 [installed]
libxdmcp6/cosmic,now 1:1.1.2-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxext6/cosmic,now 2:1.3.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxfixes3/cosmic,now 1:5.0.3-1 amd64 [installed]
libxfont2/cosmic,now 1:2.0.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxi6/cosmic,now 2:1.7.9-1 amd64 [installed]
libxinerama1/cosmic,now 2:1.1.4-1 amd64 [installed]
libxkbfile1/cosmic,now 1:1.0.9-2 amd64 [installed]
libxmu6/cosmic,now 2:1.1.2-2 amd64 [installed]
libxmuu1/cosmic,now 2:1.1.2-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libxrandr2/cosmic,now 2:1.5.1-1 amd64 [installed]
libxrender1/cosmic,now 1:0.9.10-1 amd64 [installed]
libxres1/cosmic,now 2:1.2.0-2 amd64 [installed]
libxss1/cosmic,now 1:1.2.3-1 amd64 [installed]
libxt6/cosmic,now 1:1.1.5-1 amd64 [installed]
libxtst6/cosmic,now 2:1.2.3-1 amd64 [installed]
libxv1/cosmic,now 2:1.0.11-1 amd64 [installed]
libxvmc1/cosmic,now 2:1.0.10-1 amd64 [installed]
libxxf86dga1/cosmic,now 2:1.1.4-1 amd64 [installed]
libxxf86vm1/cosmic,now 1:1.1.4-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-xkit/cosmic,cosmic,now 0.5.0ubuntu2 all [installed]
sysinfo/cosmic,cosmic,now 0.7-10.1 all [installed]
xorg/cosmic,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
xorg-docs-core/cosmic,cosmic,now 1:1.7.1-1.1 all [installed]
xserver-xorg/cosmic,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-core/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 2:1.20.1-3ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-all/cosmic,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-evdev/cosmic,now 1:2.10.6-1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-libinput/cosmic,now 0.28.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/cosmic,now 1.9.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-wacom/cosmic,now 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-legacy/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 2:1.20.1-3ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-all/cosmic,now 1:7.7+19ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/cosmic,now 19.0.0+git1903111934.6ee857~oibaf~c amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-ati/cosmic,now 1:19.0.0+git1903151930.4407c7~oibaf~c amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev/cosmic,now 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-intel/cosmic,now 2:2.99.917+git1903011933.6afed3~oibaf~c amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/cosmic,now 1:1.0.16+git1902201323.ec2b45~oibaf~c amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-qxl/cosmic,now 0.1.5-2build2 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon/cosmic,now 1:19.0.0+git1903151930.4407c7~oibaf~c amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vesa/cosmic,now 1:2.4.0-1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vmware/cosmic,now 1:13.3.0-2build1 amd64 [installed]
```